# Python TCP socket connection between Linux and Windows10 not working as expected

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, python, tcp

**I am trying to establish a TCP connection and sending packets over a python socket server-client. I am using Windows 10 as my main system and VM Kali-Linux on the other side**

I used Windows as a client and as a server, same for Linux.

The error occurs when I try to establish the connection, it throws error on Windows and just stops forever in Linux.

I checked the specified port with nmap in both sides, where:

```
windows side as client: 
PORT      STATE     SERVICE
9119/tcp  closed    mxit
          ------

linux side as client:
PORT      STATE     SERVICE
9119/tcp  filtered  mxit
          --------
```

When I scan the ports in the same system which hosts, the port is correctly open and I can send packets through it.

Is this a case of me taking no notice of something or is it more complex to send packets between different OSes?

If requested, I can paste the code but I am sure not doing anything wrong and it is just very simple code.

Some help or ideas to try solve this?

**Update**: Using VMware bridged connection. I have correct internet connection on both systems and also can I created a web server and open them in the other system.

Firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it changing the IP where was opening the port. I was using `127.0.0.1` and changed it to `0.0.0.0`.

I realized it because when I tried to scan my own IP address (not `127.0.0.1`, but which is recognized by the network e.g `192.168.0.*`) it shows the port closed too.

Comment: Great self-solving of this. And when you said this in your question, “If requested, I can paste the code but I am sure not doing anything wrong and it is just very simple code.” It seems like if you shared the code, we would have seen the `127.0.0.1` and such. Never bind on `127.0.0.1` unless you truly want localhost only access.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it later, its true.
Thanks dude